# nearest timestamp price - ready data structure in Python?

Tags: python, timestamp, containers, finance, closest

Price interpolation. Python data structure for efficient near miss searches?

I have price data

```
[1427837961000.0, 243.586], [1427962162000.0, 245.674], [1428072262000.0, 254.372], [1428181762000.0, 253.366], ...
```

with the first dimension a timestamp, and the second a price.

Now I want to know the price which is nearest to a given timestamp e.g. to 1427854534654.

What is the best Python container, data structure, or algorithm to solve this many hundred or thousand times per second? It is a standard problem, and has to be solved in many applications, so there should be a ready and optimized solution.

I have Googled, and found only bits and pieces that I could build upon - but I guess this question is so common, that the whole data structure should be ready as a module?

---

EDIT: Solved.

I used [JuniorCompressor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29526502/3693375) with my [bugfix for future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525050/nearest-timestamp-price-ready-data-structure-in-python/29526502#comment47232453_29526502) dates.

The performance is fantastic:

3000000 calls took 12.82 seconds, so 0.00000427 per call (length of data = 1143).

Thanks a lot! StackOverFlow is great, and you helpers are the best!

Comment: a sorted list of timestamps ... then use `bisect` to find the nearest index

Comment: If an answer worked for you then accept it rather than putting "(Solved!)" in the title please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common for this problem to have your data sorted by the timestamp value and then binary search for every possible query. Binary search can be performed using the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
data = [
    [1427837961000.0, 243.586], 
    [1427962162000.0, 245.674], 
    [1428072262000.0, 254.372], 
    [1428181762000.0, 253.366]
]


data.sort(key=lambda l: l[0]) # Sort by timestamp
timestamps = [l[0] for l in data] # Extract timestamps

import bisect

def find_closest(t):
    idx = bisect.bisect_left(timestamps, t) # Find insertion point

    # Check which timestamp with idx or idx - 1 is closer
    if idx > 0 and abs(timestamps[idx] - t) > abs(timestamps[idx - 1] - t):
         idx -= 1

    return data[idx][1] # Return price
```

We can test like this:

```
>>> find_closest(1427854534654)
243.586
```

If we have `n` queries and `m` timestamp values, then each query needs `O(log m)` time. So the total time needed is `O(n * log m)`.

In the above algorithm we search between two indexes. If we use only the midpoints of the timestamp intervals, we can simplify even more and create a faster search:

```
midpoints = [(a + b) / 2 for a, b in zip(timestamps, timestamps[1:])]
def find_closest_through_midpoints(t):
    return data[bisect.bisect_left(midpoints, t)][1]
```

Comment: great! I will take that as my solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a small correction, to allow for extrapolations ABOVE the given range of timestamps:

if idx == len (timestamps) or (idx > 0 and abs(timestamps[idx] - t) > abs(timestamps[idx - 1] - t)):

Comment: Implemented it, and measured its performance:

3000000 calls took 12.82 seconds, 
so 0.00000427 per call 
(length of data = 1143)

Comment: Is it possible to arrange data in such a way find operation will be in constant time instead of O(LogN) ? . E.g. using dictionary kind of node structure where hh[] :mm[] : ss[]  will become my arrays so finding will always be in constant. considering we have only 24 hrs, 60 mins in each hr, 60 seconds in each min etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get nearest value

```
l = [ [1427837961000.0, 243.586], [1427962162000.0, 245.674], [1428072262000.0, 254.372], [1428181762000.0, 253.366]]
check_value = 1427854534654
>>>min(l, key=lambda x:abs(x[0]-check_value))[0]
1427837961000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I used [JuniorCompressor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29526502/3693375) with my [bugfix for future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525050/nearest-timestamp-price-ready-data-structure-in-python/29526502#comment47232453_29526502) dates.

The performance is fantastic:

3000000 calls took 12.82 seconds, so 0.00000427 per call (length of data = 1143).

Thanks a lot! StackOverFlow is great, and you helpers are the best!